# JUnit 5 test case runs, but not in debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, junit5

I have two projects in eclipse. The `3DCoordinates` project calculates 3D coordinates and makes the conversion from one to another. The second `AstroCoordinates` project accesses the first project but defines coordinate systems used in astronomy only.

All the JUnit 5 tests for `3DCoordinates` run now without problems. I wrote for the `AstroCoordinates` in a similar manner a coordinate class called `HorizontalCoordinates` with the appropriate tests. The tests have still errors when running, but, coming to my problem, when I try to debug them, the test stops after opening the `Class.class` file.

I searched the Internet, but couldn't find an explanation for this – to me – strange behaviour. Do you know about this issue? What can be the reason for it?

**Edit:**
Here, you can see the result of the normal test run:
[image: Normal run of HorizontalCoordinatesTest with JUnit 5]
The debug test stops without any error message, after the `Class.class` file opens.
[image: Debug run of HorizontalCoordinatesTest with JUnit 5]
No error messages occur.
[image: Debug run of HorizontalCoordinatesTest with JUnit 5 stops w/o errors]

Comment: Can you give more details, such as your code? What is `Class`? (As you mention in another comment that you don't have a class `Class`, what does it mean that _"the `Class.class` file is opened"_?) What means _"the test stops"_? (Do you get an error message? Does your debugger terminate or freeze?)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Please see the edit above.

Comment: Can you check whether your debugger hasn't just hit a [breakpoint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2022.1/using-breakpoints.html) and waits for you to resume the program execution? (FYI: [`java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) is an internal class of the Java language, which cannot be extended.)

Comment: There are no breakpoints. But if I put breakpoints, I never reach them. If I empty all the test cases, the debug does not make any problems. If I add the contents, it will stop after opening the mentioned Java class.

Comment: Interesting!  I'm not yet convinced that the java process has already terminated, so I'd try to find out what the process is doing (or waiting for). You could use tools like [`jps`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jps.html) to find the process ID and then tools like [`jstack`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jstack.html) to get a thread dump or connect a tool like [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/), but in case you don't have experience with them, it might be difficult to explain here.

Comment: According to the screenshot the main thread is paused. What happens when you click _Resume_ (F8)? What's in your _Breakpoints_ view? In the debug configuration, is _Stop in main_ checked or not?

Answer (score -1):

If your class is actually named Class, try renaming it.

Comment: `Class.class` is a Java class that is somehow extended by other classes. It is unlikely to be used directly. I do not have ever named a class `Class`, and I never had a case like this.